# Clojure: Could not locate test2__init.class, test2.clj or test2.cljc on classpath in Cider

Tags: clojure

I have two files test.clj and test2.clj in the same directory.

I want to import the functions from test2.clj

test.clj looks like this:

```
(ns test
  (:require [test2 :refer :all])
)
```

test2.clj like this:

```
(defn showworld []
    (println "hello world")
)
```

But when i execute test.clj in cider, i get:
Could not locate test2__init.class, test2.clj or test2.cljc on classpath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the namespace declaration in test2.clj. When we `:require` something, we are requiring the namespace (not the file).

Try changing test2.clj to the following:

```clj
(ns test2)

(defn showworld []
    (println "hello world"))
```

Comment: Thanks, i also found, that i have to eval the buffer also to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Though you are providing a file name as `test2.clj`, that's not sufficient,  you should also have  namespace declaration which we do with `ns` , and then code inside `test2.clj` goes as following :

```
(ns test2)

(defn showworld []
    (println "hello world")
)
```